# Pendulum with changing length over time. What's wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I tried to find the equation of this pendulum, but I think I did something wrong. I know I have to get the Bessel's equation but I can't see it. 
It's a simple 2-D pendulum, without any dissipation.
The length is $l$.

\begin{gather}
x(t)= l(t)  \sin\theta(t), \\
y(t)=l(t)  \cos\theta(t), \\
\dot x(t)= \dot l(t) \sin\theta(t) + l(t) \dot \theta(t) \cos\theta(t) \\
\dot y(t)= \dot l(t) \cos\theta(t) - l(t) \dot \theta(t) \sin\theta 
\end{gather}

and:
\begin{equation}
\dot x^2 + \dot y^2 = \dot l^2 + l^2 \dot \theta^2
\end{equation}

The potential and kinetic energy:
\begin{gather}
V=-mgy= -mgl(t) \cos\theta(t), \\
T=\frac{m}{2} (\dot l^2(t)+ l^2(t) \dot \theta^2(t))
\end{gather}

So the Langrangian is:
\begin{equation}
L=T-V= \frac{m}{2}(\dot l^2 + l^2 \dot \theta^2) + mgl \cos\theta
\end{equation}

After this, we get:
\begin{gather}
\frac{ \partial L}{\partial \theta} = -mgl \sin\theta, \\
\frac{ d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot \theta}= m2l \dot l \dot \theta +ml^2 \ddot \theta.
\end{gather}

From thism we get the equation:
\begin{equation}
\ddot \theta + 2 \dot l \dot \theta = g \sin\theta.
\end{equation}

And for the radial part:

\begin{gather}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial l} = ml \dot \theta^2 + mg \cos\theta , \\
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot l}= m \ddot l.
\end{gather}

The equation is:
\begin{equation}
\dot l = l \dot \theta^2 + g \cos\theta
\end{equation}

My question is how can I get to the Bessel's equation from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, two tiny mistakes: your $\theta$ equation is missing an $\ell$, and the sign of $g  \sin \theta$ is flipped. That is, it should be

$$ 2 \dot{\ell} \dot{\theta} + \ell \ddot{\theta} = -g \sin \theta
$$

Now, I have not seen Bessel equation emerge for pendulum dynamics for arbitrary length variability. It only arises, as far as I have seen, for the linearly-changing length, that is, for $\ell=\ell_0+v t$, and even in that case, under the small-$\theta$ approximation, to the first non-zero order or $\theta$.

In this special case, the equation reduces to $(\ell_0+v t) \ddot{\theta}+2 v \dot{\theta}+g \theta = 0$. There is a change-of-variables that transforms this into Bessel's ode, which is $\psi= \theta \sqrt{\ell}$ and $\phi=\frac{2}{v}\sqrt{\ell g}$. 
The calculations can be googled, and for example can be found [here](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/deproj/sp05/atrav/thepitandthependulum.pdf). This eventuates in the Bessel equation for the $\psi$ and $\phi$ pair.

Another pendulum-related case that I know where Bessel's equation emerges is when the deformation of the rope from a straight line is taken into account, and the first corrections invoke Bessel equations.

Other than these two special cases, I don't think one can evoke Bessel's equation in pendulum dynamics.

Comment: Can you please link to the problem where the deformation of the rope is treated?

Comment: See for example, Equation 4 in  (http://iopscience.iop.org/0143-0807/29/6/010/pdf/ejp8_6_010.pdf), Equation 5 in  (http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/46/4/10.1119/1.11335), and Equation 9 in  (http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022460X85700223/1-s2.0-S0022460X85700223-main.pdf?_tid=b1403d32-1b2a-11e4-a047-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1407083270_2a4af8eec2771e70d17f148f708ac983)

Answer (score 1):

The correct equation of motion for $\theta$ is
\begin{equation}
l\ddot \theta + 2 \dot l \dot \theta = -g \sin\theta.
\end{equation}
Now if you assume $l(t)=l_{0}+vt$ then you will get a Bessel Differential Equations.
\begin{equation}
\ddot \theta+\frac{2}{l}\dot \theta+\frac{g}{v^{2}l}\theta=0
\end{equation}
The solution for which is the Bessel Function. ($\sin\theta$ approximated by $\theta$ for small angle)